# Azure Blob CONTENT-MD is null for some files

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

blob files have `CONTENT-MD5  -`. When I am trying to read it from properties, its giving value as `null`. It's happening with few files only, others having their md5. for me, It's not possible to re-upload these files as they are stored here by an ADF job. Is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: I have met this issue, I don't why and didn't find the reason. Just as I know, the only solution is download these no CONTENT-MD5 files from the Blob storage,  re-upload to Blob Storage and overwrite the old one. Then the files will have CONTENT-MD5. If you don't have the permission to access the blob, I'm afraid there's no good solution for this issue.

Comment: Hi @gavisic, If the answer is helpful for you,  can you please accept it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you very much and have a good day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have met this issue, I don't why and didn't find the reason.

Just as I know, the only solution is download these no CONTENT-MD5 files from the Blob storage, re-upload to Blob Storage and overwrite the old one. Then the files will have CONTENT-MD5. If you don't have the permission to access the blob, I'm afraid there's no good solution for this issue.

For example, I checked my storage and find a file (created by Data Factory) with no CONTENT-MD5 property:
[image]

I just download it and upload again:

[image]

Then the file will have the CONTENT-MD5 property:
[image]

During the uploading, I think Azure will re-create the CONTENT-MD5 for it.